# Qt Licenses with Multiple Users Per Machine

Tags: c++, qt

We have a situation where we're trying to set up a VM for Qt-based development. This is Windows 10, Qt 15.14.14, Visual Studio 2019. We are using the commercial version of Qt.

The machine is set up and the project will build when the use is Administrator, but not when an "ordinary" user logs in. Qt reports that it's unlicensed. Each user is properly licensed, but of course only one license gets included during Qt installation.

Each user will have their own VM, so it's not the end of the world if they can't be shared, but the difficulty is that they each have to install Qt for themselves so that the license is applied. Our administration is trying to set these up and have them ready.

Is there an easy workaround, or is there something simple we can do for each user so that the appropriate license is invoked when they're each logged on?

Comment: Contact Qt support.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the Roaming folder from the installation user to the other users resolved the problem.